# Using load balancer with moxi

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, membase

I'm using Moxi proxy with Membase cluster. And main problem that Moxi can connect only to one server, so if i want to use it right i need balancer that will spread connections all over cluster.
I tried to use Nginx proxy, but as i saw something is killing the connection.

Does anyone have working setup of balancer + Moxi proxy?

Appreciated for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-posted: http://groups.google.com/group/membase/browse_thread/thread/c48c368e23a34500

Comment: Just in case someone will be need it. Multiple URL's can be specified in the cluster REST/URL config file, but must be separated by '|' (vertical 'pipe' bar) characters (because the comma character is already used as a key=value delimiter).